# How to show grammar is not LL(1) and convert grammar to LL(1)

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, compiler-theory

I'm trying to find the ambiguity in this grammar so I can remove it and convert it to LL(1), however for the life of me I can't find the ambiguity. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
D -> if (C) {S} | if (C) {S} else {S}
S -> D | SA | A
A -> V = T;
V -> x | y
T -> 1 | 2
C -> true | false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar is not ambiguous. Nonetheless, it is not LL(1) because when the lookahead token is `if`, it is not possible to know which of the two productions for `D` will be used.

To make it LL(1), you will need to [left-factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#Left_Factoring) `D`.

Comment: Additionally, the production for `S` is left-recursive, so the grammar isn't LL(anything).

Comment: Thank you both, it is correct I had to left factor D and remove the left recursion from S